# Apache Camel: properties created during the split are lost after the split

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm kinda struggling with lost exchange properties that are created during the split phase (I need to use them after split).

So basically:

```
from(MY_ROUTE)
    .routeId(MY_ROUTE_ID)
    .to(PREPARE_ADDITIONAL_PROPERTIES_ROUTE)
    .process(myProcessor)
    ...

from(PREPARE_ADDITIONAL_PROPERTIES_ROUTE)
    .routeId(PREPARE_ADDITIONAL_PROPERTIES_ROUTE_ID)
    .split(several_elements_to_split).streaming()
        .to(CREATE_SOME_PROPERTIES_ROUTE)
    .end();
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to process the data (some Objects) that I've set to properties of exchange in route `CREATE_SOME_PROPERTIES_ROUTE` in `myProcessor`, but these properties are lost/missing after getting out of split phase.

Is there any way to recover the properties in `myProcessor`? Or to avoid losing them after split?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a custom `AggregationStrategy` to the splitter where you propagate the properties you want to keep

Comment: So I understand that if I create my own class that extends `AggregationStrategy` and I `@Override` method `aggregate`, I should set new property on newExchange with the values from oldExchange?
And when/where should I use that `.aggregate()` in route? Right after `.streaming()`?

Comment: Yeah see the splitter documentation, it shows how to use a custom agg strategy: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/core/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/split-eip.adoc#split-aggregate-requestreply-sample

Comment: Hi Claus, thank you so much, it was really helpful.
At the beginning I was trying to put somewhere `.aggregate()`, but then saw an example provided by you on github and putting `AggregationStrategy` inside `.split()` brackets (as an argument) solved the problem (so `.split(several_elements_to_split, new MyCustomAggregationStrategy())`.

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in the comments, you would need to use an Aggregator.  When splitting, Camel basically creates new messages and new exchanges, so setting properties or headers inside your split wouldn't carry over as the Unit of Work terminates when the split ends.